# How to embed a .png in a .swf to show in flash app (DIY map)

Tags: flash, png, converters

I am using the cool map making program DIY map and i want to keep my points as images. However, you can only set .swfs and jpgs as image points. The author of the program says quote:

> Unfortunately, Flash can not load GIF’s or PNG’s dynamically, but you can embed these into an SWF. PNG’s embedded into an SWF will also display their alpha channel nicely. My default info icon is a PNG with a little transparent shadow. Note, bitmap images tend to show up a little crunchy when scaled in Flash so avoid fine borders and detail.

However I am wondering how i actually get my .png in a .swf to use it. Sorry if this is a noob question, I know nothing about flash.

For example, I want to keep this as a .swf with the transparency:
[alt text http://www.onecool.com/images/icons/server.png](http://www.onecool.com/images/icons/server.png)

EDIT:
this is the programs website:
http://backspace.com/mapapp/

Comment: What program is this, is it called DIY map? Flash -can- load gif's and png's dynamically so this sounds like it's a restriction of whatever other program you're using. Have you tried just passing a png in to see what happens?

Comment: yeah, i have tried passing in a .png and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is actually deceivingly simple in its answer. Download Flash CS4 Professional, import the .png you want to convert to .swf onto the board and just export it as a .swf. I guess the reason I couldn't find an answer to this problem was because it was so trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Is this Flash CS4 Professional? Flash CS3 Professional? Flex 3.3 SDK? Flex 4 SDK? If you are using some version of Flash, then you can just embed the image in your Flash (*.fla) file. If you are using some version of Flex, you can use the [Embed(source="path/to/source/image.png")] to embed the image. See [this link](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=853).